# How to display JSON Value in Angular JS

Tags: angularjs

I want to read and display the below JSON Code using angular JS.I tried but unable to get the output.

I used ng-repeat to get and print this data but getting blank data.Iterated shipmentsAllInfo and got shipmentLst then iterated to SingleShipment then shipmentDetails and try to print its variable

Can Some one Please help me in fixing this code.

```
Json :
{
  "shipmentsAllInfo": {
    "shipmentSingle": [
      {
        "delivered": "5",
        "exception": "4",
        "intransit": "2",
        "manifest": "1",
        "outForDelivery": "3",
        "shipmentDetails": [
          {
            "referenceNumbers": "2",
            "trackingNumber": "1"
          },
          {
            "referenceNumbers": "4",
            "trackingNumber": "3"
          }
        ],
        "total": "7",
        "upsAccount": "Andrew",
        "voids": "6"
      },
      {
        "delivered": "5",
        "exception": "4",
        "intransit": "2",
        "manifest": "1",
        "outForDelivery": "3",
        "shipmentDetails": [
          {
            "referenceNumbers": "2",
            "trackingNumber": "1"
          },
          {
            "referenceNumbers": "4",
            "trackingNumber": "3"
          }
        ],
        "total": "7",
        "upsAccount": "Andrew",
        "voids": "6"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your angular code with the bug?

Comment: Redundant key `shipmentsAllInfo`; debug your code and follow your docs please

Answer (score 0):

In your controller:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  var json = {
  "shipmentsAllInfo": {
    "shipmentSingle": [
      {
        "delivered": "5",
        "exception": "4",
        "intransit": "2",
        "manifest": "1",
        "outForDelivery": "3",
        "shipmentDetails": [
          {
            "referenceNumbers": "2",
            "trackingNumber": "1"
          },
          {
            "referenceNumbers": "4",
            "trackingNumber": "3"
          }
        ],
        "total": "7",
        "upsAccount": "Andrew",
        "voids": "6"
      },
      {
        "delivered": "5",
        "exception": "4",
        "intransit": "2",
        "manifest": "1",
        "outForDelivery": "3",
        "shipmentDetails": [
          {
            "referenceNumbers": "2",
            "trackingNumber": "1"
          },
          {
            "referenceNumbers": "4",
            "trackingNumber": "3"
          }
        ],
        "total": "7",
        "upsAccount": "Andrew",
        "voids": "6"
      }
    ]
  }};

  $scope.shipmentinfo= json.shipmentsAllInfo;        
});
```

And then in your html:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
 <table class="table table-bordered" ng-repeat="module in shipmentinfo.shipmentSingle">
 <tr>
    <td>
        <p>delivered: {{ module.delivered }}</p>
        <p>exception: {{ module.exception }}</p>
        The rest of you output
        <div ng-repeat="sd in module.shipmentDetails">
          <p>referenceNumbers: {{ sd.referenceNumbers }}</p>
          <p>trackingNumber: {{ sd.trackingNumber }}</p>

        </div>
        etc...
    </td>
 </tr>
</table>
</body>
```